# Why doesn't SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETE secure my file?

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift

I'm creating a new database file in my app. When I launch iExplorer, I am able to copy the database file to my mac and then open it with ease.

Why isn't this securing the data file so that it is unreadable outside my app?

```
var status = sqlite3_open_v2(dbFilePath.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, &_sqliteDB, SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE|SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil)
if status != SQLITE_OK {
    return false
}

return true
```

The same thing happens with Objective-C. Just working in Swift at the moment.

Is it possible, that by unlocking the device and then running iExplorer to get the file, that the OS is decrypting the file as it is being copied by iExplorer? I would think not.

Comment: Maybe because it's not a defined flag: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_open_autoproxy.html

Comment: It's in the sqlite3.h file and was talked about at WWDC in 2012. Probably a special build in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is only encrypted when the device is locked. Here are the protection levels:

- No protection—The file is not encrypted on disk.
- Complete—The file is encrypted and inaccessible while the device is locked.
- Complete unless already open—The file is encrypted. A closed file is inaccessible while the device is locked. After the user unlocks the device, your app can open the file and use it. If the user locks the device while the file is open, though, your app can continue to access it.
- Complete until first login—The file is encrypted and inaccessible until after the device has booted and the user has unlocked it once.

See the Apple documentation (scroll to) [Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11)

Comment: So it is as I suspected. Once the device is unlocked, the OS is decrypting it as I read it off with iExplorer.

Comment: The concept is that the user has access to everything on the iDevice, it is his. If one cares about securing access by others they must add a lock code and a timeout, hopefully turning on the extended passcode capability.

Comment: I can live with that. Makes checking the data file during development and testing a lot easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

File protection, via NSFileProtectionComplete on iOS, relies on the device having a Pin set.

Comment: I have a passcode set on the device. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how this flag should work? I would expect that the file would be encrypted such that when copied to my Mac, I couldn't read it with other apps that can open SQLite files.

Comment: Have you considered a solution like SQLCypher?